# EventKit Predicate Choices

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar, eventkit

The app I'm developing will write events to a calendar on the user's phone. I was thinking of preceeding my app's event with a prefix like myapp: so I can find my events in the event store to display in a tableview.

However, it seems that the only predicate available is based upon a start and end date (– predicateForEventsWithStartDate:endDate:calendars:) when I review the ios eventkit [framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/EKEventStore/enumerateEventsMatchingPredicate%3ausingBlock%3a). Am I reading that right?

Should I just then create a calendar for just my app on the phone or is there another way to identify my events beside dates?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One other option would be to have local storage (sqlite, coredata etc...) which indexes into the event.  Each event has as event id and you can you retrieve the event from the store via eventWithIdentifier.

Not sure what your data access patterns are but that also allows you to quickly store data within your app that you can query effieciently (with a powerful predicates and sql syntax).  Your local results could just return eventIds and in the the table view call backs you get the id for that row and retrieve from the events store.

Just another option ...

Comment: Hey, that's a great idea, I didn't know I could do that. Just to be sure I understand, when I create an event I also capture the event id, and then store it in my core data store in an entity. Then I pull from the event store based upon these event ids i pull from my core data entity?

Comment: That's the basic idea.  In that scheme, you have to decide who's the master of data and worry about out of sync data.  I would suggest querying to return ids and then getting the data you display from the event store.  You could also have a fall back strategy or even options to detect it's missing and push back to the event store (sorry don't know alot about your app).  If that's the case, you also store the data in the db which allows for rich querying but you prefer showing the data from the event store.  A little more work but much more robust.  You could also re-populate a calendar etc...

Comment: Thank you very much, this is an innovative approach.